# Select a dict from a list where one value does not matches another with jq

Tags: json, jq

There is the following data structure (list of dicts):

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "value": "value1",
        "default": "value1"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "value": "blafasel",
        "default": "value2"
    }
]
```

We are now looking for a `jq` filter to get all dicts where `value` and `default` are not equal.

Comment: Nice, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: `cat structure.json | jq 'select(.[].value == .[].default)'`

Comment: Always add your attempts in your post, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the dicts by `.[]`, select only those that have the value different to the default:

```
jq '.[] | select (.value != .default)' file.json
```